# CronJob - scheduale a job to run every 12 hours starting immediately

Tags: unix, cron

Is there a way to define a cron jon that will run every 12 hours but will start immediately?
For example if now its 14:30 , and I start cron, I'll want the job to run on: 15:00 , 3:00, 15:00 and etc.

But if I start cron at 16:22, I want it to be:
17:00, 7:00, 17:00 and etc..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have your entry as:

```
0 00,12 * * * /script/
```

This will run every day at midnight and 12pm, and then edit the schedule whenever you start and restart cron (although not sure why you'd want a varying schedule dependant upon when the cron server was started or stopped).

edit:

How about

```
0 */12 * * * /script
```

or if you want it to run on boot

```
* */12 * * * /script
```

you may need to add a sleep to your script of say 5 minutes (unless it's ready instantenously)

Comment: Thanks, I guess there's not other choice. The reason is  that when I'm loading the system I need the job to start and collect data, and I also need a gap of 12 hours between each run.